# SyntaxError: Unexpected token "<" when using an external Javascript file

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call an external Javascript file as the Javascript for my HTML document. But I get this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token "<" on line 1. So clearly it is acknowledging the file. But what I don't understand why it is throwing an error. I looked around and it seems no one else is has ever gotten this problem.

This is the HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing</title>
<script src="displaydate.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.<br>
<a href=http://www.google.com>google</a>
</p>


</body>
</html>
```

This is my Javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function todaydate(){
var today_date= new Date();
var myyear=today_date.getYear();
var mymonth=today_date.getMonth()+1;
var mytoday=today_date.getDate();
alert(myyear+"//"+mymonth+"//"+mytoday);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the script-tags in the external file. Remove them and it will work.

Comment: Exactly right it worked at once now, thanks, I have been looking around for an answer for some time now.

Answer (score 4):

A JavaScript file should contain only JavaScript.

Remove the HTML `<script>` tags from it.